# Facing issue while deploying Docker images through AWS-Greengrass Connector Service

Tags: docker, containers, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

BACKGROUND:

1. We are trying to deploy App as a docker container through AWS-Greengrass Connector Service to the edge device (Running Greengrass core as container in Linux env).
2. We are configuring the greengrass group connector in cloud for docker app deployment.

ISSUES:

While deploying from AWS greengrass group (AWS cloud), we are able to see successful deployment message, but application is not getting deployed to the edge device (running greengrass core as container).

LOGS:

1. DockerApplicationDeploymentLog:

[2020-11-05T10:35:42.632Z][FATAL]-lambda_runtime.py:381,Failed to initialize Lambda runtime due to exception: "getgrnam(): name not found: 'docker'"
[2020-11-05T10:35:44.789Z][WARN]-ipc_client.py:162,deprecated arg port=8000 will be ignored
[2020-11-05T10:35:45.012Z][WARN]-ipc_client.py:162,deprecated arg port=8000 will be ignored
[2020-11-05T10:35:45.012Z][INFO]-docker_deployer.py:41,docker deployer starting up
[2020-11-05T10:35:45.012Z][INFO]-docker_deployer.py:45,checking inputs
[2020-11-05T10:35:45.012Z][INFO]-docker_deployer.py:52,docker group permissions
[2020-11-05T10:35:45.02Z][FATAL]-lambda_runtime.py:141,Failed to import handler function "handlers.function_handler" due to exception: "getgrnam(): name not found: 'docker'"

2. RuntimeSystemLog:

[2020-11-05T10:31:49.78Z][DEBUG]-Restart worker because it was killed.  {"workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "funcArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:aws:function:DockerApplicationDeployment:6"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.78Z][DEBUG]-Reserve worker.        {"workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "funcArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:aws:function:DockerApplicationDeployment:6"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.78Z][DEBUG]-Doing start attempt:   {"Attempt count": 0, "workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "funcArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:aws:function:DockerApplicationDeployment:6"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.78Z][DEBUG]-Creating directory.    {"dir": "/greengrass/ggc/packages/1.11.0/var/lambda/8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.78Z][DEBUG]-changed ownership      {"path": "/greengrass/ggc/packages/1.11.0/var/lambda/8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "new uid": 121, "new gid": 121}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.782Z][DEBUG]-Resolving environment variable        {"Variable": "PYTHONPATH=/greengrass/ggc/deployment/lambda/arn.aws.lambda.ap-south-1.aws.function.DockerApplicationDeployment.6"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.79Z][DEBUG]-Resolving environment variable {"Variable": "PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.799Z][DEBUG]-Resolving environment variable        {"Variable": "DOCKER_DEPLOYER_DOCKER_COMPOSE_DESTINATION_FILE_PATH=/home/ggc_user"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.82Z][DEBUG]-Creating new worker.   {"functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:aws:function:DockerApplicationDeployment:6", "workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.82Z][DEBUG]-Starting worker process.       {"workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.829Z][DEBUG]-Worker process started.       {"workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "pid": 20471}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.83Z][DEBUG]-Start work result:     {"workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "funcArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:aws:function:DockerApplicationDeployment:6", "state": "Starting", "initDurationSeconds": 0.012234454}
[2020-11-05T10:31:49.831Z][INFO]-Created worker.        {"functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:aws:function:DockerApplicationDeployment:6", "workerId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5", "pid": 20471}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.155Z][DEBUG]-Received a credential provider request        {"serverLambdaArn": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:GGTES", "clientId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.156Z][DEBUG]-WorkManager getting work      {"workerId": "148f7a1a-168f-40a5-682d-92e00d56a5df", "funcArn": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:GGTES", "invocationId": "955c2c43-1187-4001-7988-4213b95eb584"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.156Z][DEBUG]-Successfully GET work.        {"invocationId": "955c2c43-1187-4001-7988-4213b95eb584", "fromWorkerId": "148f7a1a-168f-40a5-682d-92e00d56a5df", "ofFunction": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:GGTES"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.156Z][DEBUG]-POST work result.     {"invocationId": "955c2c43-1187-4001-7988-4213b95eb584", "ofFunction": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:GGTES"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.156Z][DEBUG]-WorkManager putting work result.      {"workerId": "148f7a1a-168f-40a5-682d-92e00d56a5df", "invocationId": "955c2c43-1187-4001-7988-4213b95eb584"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.156Z][DEBUG]-WorkManager put work result successfully.     {"workerId": "148f7a1a-168f-40a5-682d-92e00d56a5df", "invocationId": "955c2c43-1187-4001-7988-4213b95eb584"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.156Z][DEBUG]-Successfully POST work result.        {"invocationId": "955c2c43-1187-4001-7988-4213b95eb584", "ofFunction": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:GGTES"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.157Z][DEBUG]-Handled a credential provider request {"clientId": "8b0ee21d-e481-4d27-5e30-cb4d912547f5"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.158Z][DEBUG]-GET work item.        {"fromWorkerId": "148f7a1a-168f-40a5-682d-92e00d56a5df", "ofFunction": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:GGTES"}
[2020-11-05T10:31:53.158Z][DEBUG]-Worker timer doesn't exist.   {"workerId": "148f7a1a-168f-40a5-682d-92e00d56a5df"}

Answer (score 0):

Did you doublecheck to meet the requirments listed in

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/docker-app-connector.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/docker-app-connector.html#docker-app-connector-linux-user

I dont know this particular error, but it complains about some missing basic user/group settings:

```
[2020-11-05T10:35:42.632Z][FATAL]-lambda_runtime.py:381,Failed to initialize Lambda runtime due to exception: "getgrnam(): name not found: 'docker'"
```